# python & zeroMQ -- Capacity to Handle Messages of Large Size?

Tags: python, zeromq

I'd like to use `python` to build an app that is similar to [`zeroMQ`'s ventilator / sink scheme](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer)

Suppose that we have **10 Workers**, all running on the same *multi-core* server.

Let's say that every *2[sec]* or so, each **Worker** pushes to the **Sink** a message of size 5[MB]. So, the **Sink** has to handle a total of 50[MB] ( = 10 x 5[MB] ) every *2[sec]* or so.

Had the 10 **Workers** been on different machines, I *know* that *the network* could have been a potential bottleneck.

Had the 10 **Workers** had to write their data to disk (I/O), I *know* that *the disk* could have been a potential bottleneck.

Given the fact that all the **10 Workers** are **on the *same machine***, what bottlenecks should one expect?

For example, can the same **10 Workers** each push a message of size 10[MB] every *2[sec]* or so? 
Can they push a message of size 20[MB] every *2[sec]* or so?

What are `zmq`'s limitations?

What types of bottlenecks should one expect when using `python` and `zeroMQ` in a `Linux` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `PUSH`/`PULL` on the same server I've been been able to max out writing to a raid array @ 400MB/sec (bottle-necked by write speed). There are 10GbE benchmark results [here](http://www.zeromq.org/results:10gbe-tests-v031). I'd suggest constructing some simple benchmarks, performance is going to be dependent on a lot of factors like message format, size, etc.

For example a completely trivial benchmark shows zeromq capable of sending 100 10mb messages in 12.3 ms on my machine:

```
# server
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
reciever = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
reciever.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')

while True:
    reciever.recv()

# client
import os, zmq

context = zmq.Context()
pusher = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
pusher.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')

message = ' ' * 10485760

>>> %timeit pusher.send(message)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: zeekay, thank you. Please note -- my example does not involve the **Workers** writing to disk -- simply sending the data over to the **Sink** (meaning, no disk is involved). Any hints what types of bottlenecks I should expect?

Comment: It's hard to say, you could bottleneck yourself in a lot of ways unrelated to zeromq. What are your workers doing? How are you constructing messages? What protocol are you using? I'd construct a simple benchmark and test performance in your particular case. In my experience you can transfer hundreds of megabytes/sec from a single worker, assuming the messages can be constructed/processed fast enough. I have no idea what the upper limit of zeromq's performance is.

Comment: Updated answer with a simple benchmark demonstrating zeromq's performance sending 10Mb messages.

Comment: zeekay, thank you. I tried to play with `zeroMQ`, sending over messages of size 4[MB] or so, using code similar to yours. It looks like **some messages ARE NOT RECEIVED** at the server; They are sent, but I do not see them RECEIVED. why is that?

Comment: You might want to ask another question about lost messages using `PUSH`/`PULL` (or whatever you used).

Comment: Yes -- here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702187/python-zeromq-push-pull-lost-messages

Comment: If you are concerned with memory performance, you might want to be using `copy=False`, which allows you to send/recv messages without any in-memory copies.  Using the identical code above:

    `In [7]: %timeit pusher.send(message)`  
    `10 loops, best of 3: 20.5 ms per loop`  
  
    `In [8]: %timeit pusher.send(message, copy=False)`  
    `100000 loops, best of 3: 9.37 us per loop`  

So non-copying sends return *much* faster for large messages.  Note that send returning does *not* mean that the message has actually left over the wire. The actual network traffic is always hidden by 0MQ.

Comment: I don't get how to use `%timeit`, or the `In [7]:` etc. syntax. Can you please clarify how to use these?